# Zend Framework Database Insert Issue

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, insert

I'm starting out using the Zend Framework and have created a suitable model which saves data back to a database table.  The issue I am having is that the sql statement is trying to insert '?' as the value for each column in the database.  I have created the following save function which passes an array of data to the DBtable adapter functions:

```
public function save()     {
    $data = $this->getData();
    if ($data['pageId']==0) {
        $this->getDbTable()->insert($data);
    } else {
         $this->getDbTable()->update($data, array('pageId = ?' => $data['pageId']));
    }
}
```

This seems to go through the appropriate motions but the item is not added to the database and the sql statement within MySql logs looks something like:

```
insert into DB_Table ('pageId','title','body') values ('?', '?', '?');
```

Not quite sure where this is falling down, any pointers would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data should be in next format:

```
$data = array(
   'pageId' => 1,
   'title'  => 'title',
   'body'   => 'body'
);
```

Are you sure that `$this->getDbTable()` returns your db adapter?
Try to use:

```
$db = new Zend_Db_Table('table_name');
$db->insert($data);
```

Comment: Thanks, bit of a "doh" moment with the getDbTable().  Thanks for your tip.